# Hero in a stack - Flutter

Tags: routes, dart, flutter, stack

Is it possible to get the page to show on top of the Hero animation the page route is happening?

My problem is that I have a stack, and the Hero animation is at the bottom of the stack, but when the page routes the hero is on top until the page has fully routed and then the information appears suddenly on top and therefore isn't as smooth.

Is it possible for anywhere to get the Hero to route behind the others in the stack?

Comment: Hero animation always brings the hero widget to the front of everything because it is added as an OverlayEntry to the top of the Overlay. You can't avoid that in the pages from and to where the widget is flying. The only way would be to add another OverlayEntry on top.

Comment: Thought this might be the case, thanks for letting me know before I tried to delve into it any further!

Comment: @TomO'Sullivan did you actually manage to do this. I have been trying to solve this exact issue, where my toWidget is the first element in a stack.